# Subsite Passwords / Basic Authentication in Quarto

Tags: authentication, passwords, quarto

I'm creating a website project in quarto and I want to implement basic authentication. Right now I have a page `index.qmd` with some public content and a button that links to another page `syllabus.qmd`.

For now the content in `syllabus.qmd` is also open to anyone, but I would like to change it so that the page prompts the user to input a password. No username and password stuff, just one password field with a password that is common for all users. For example, if the `syllabus.qmd` password is `1234`, anyone can view the content after inputting `1234`, else it will show a message saying the password is incorrect.

I know how to do this with a local password, but for security reasons I'd like to use server-side authentication. I didn't see any documentation on this in the Quarto documentation website. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6052